# Visual Studio 2015 Selenium C# 'Using' Library NOT Found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015

[OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement NOT Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfoB6.jpg)

As you can see by the code image, I have entered the 'using' library I need to use. However, it is telling me that "SelectElement" does not exist. Does anyone here know how to go about adding the correct library?

By clicking the above link, you will see the code image.

Here is the code snippet:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace ToolsQA.Selenium_Basics
{
    class DropDownAndSelectOperations
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            // Create a new instance of the Firfox Driver
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan. 
            FromSeconds(10);

            // Launch the URL
            driver.Url = "http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice- 
            form";

            // Step 3: Select "Continents" drop down (Use Id to identify the 
            element)
            // Find "Select" element of "Single Selection" using Id locator.
            *SelectElement* oSelection = new 
            SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("continents")));
```

Comment: Hover over `SelectElement`, wait for the popup, click on "Show potential fixes", click "using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI", done.

Comment: I went in to do as you recommended only to see that option is not listed. The options given are: #1 "Generate Class "SelectElement" in new file. #2 Generate Class "SelectElement" #3 Generate Nested Class "SelectElement" and #4 Generate new type. The "using" choice is not displaying.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Support package added?

Comment: How do I check if it is installed? add ons?

Comment: If you are using NuGet, which I highly recommend, you should click on Project > Manage NuGet Packages. Click on the Installed tab and look for Selenium.Support. If you aren't using NuGet, you will have to see how dependencies are managed in your framework. The fact that the option didn't show up makes me think it's not installed. There are times when it doesn't come up initially. You may have to hover a couple times just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I have NuGet Manager installed. I have obtained the Selenium Firefox and Chrome webdrivers as well as the NUnit web adapter and drivers. Those all have the latest versions installed. That is why this is getting maddening to me. I must be missing something but what? (That is what I am asking myself anyway)

Comment: When I build I get this error: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'SelectElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Fixed - Selenium Support Package. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Selenium Support package through NuGet. That should solve the problem.